# Is there a quick way to swap outline styles?

Tags: lists, styles

For the list i'm creating, I would like to use the following structure:

I.
A.
1.

With the template I am using, however, I have:

[image]

How can I alter this aspect of the list (outline, really)?

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{comment}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Operational rules for constructing an upper line with a basic step motion}
    
    \subsection{The basic step motion}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
    
     \item The final pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic.
     
     \item The first pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic triad member a third, a fifth, or an octave above the final pitch.
     
     \item These two pitches must be joined by inserting the pitches of intervening diatonic degrees to form a descending step motion.
     
    \end{enumerate}
    \subsection{Beginning of Two-Voice Setting}

    \end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the `enumerate`

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi:} % level 1 item signs
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Alph{enumi}} % level 1 item number
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)} % level 2 item signs
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}} % level 2 item number
\begin{enumerate} % num:
\item text 
\begin{enumerate} % num)
\item text 
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
```

You can use these for topics

```
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{section}.\Alph{subsection}.}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsection}\alph{subsubsection})}
```

To change numbering.

If i.e. you want change`section`  numbering

> \renewcommand{\thesection}{ **\Roman{section}** }

Edit the bolded part.

> \renewcommand{\thesection}{**(**\arabic{section}**)**}

Comment: Thank you @oni.  I am not exactly understanding how to work this into my code, though.  I just tried it, and the text didn't even show up.  Then I tried again putting \section in front of it, and I got a number where I was expecting a roman numeral.  thought?

Comment: Last part is for what kinda numbers one wants `Alph` `A`, `alph` `b`, `Roman` `III`, `roman` `iv`, `arabic` `5`, between __{__ __}__ is the counter.